# mysql table optimize ,just two columns with datetime compare

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing, compare

This is SQL:

```
    SELECT
        f_collect_time
    FROM
        t_ov_meterorigvalue_a98ea7cee0b1111e48e0800163e002d36 a98ea7cee0b1111e48e0800163e002d36
    WHERE
        f_collect_time < '2017-05-05 00:00:00'
    AND f_meter_id = 320679
    ORDER BY
        f_collect_time DESC,
        f_meter_id
    LIMIT 1
```

my query time is 38S+

rows of table is 19093806

[the index of my table is below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIFGg.png)

[the fields of my table is below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqqNu.png)

show create table result :

```
 CREATE TABLE `t_ov_meterorigvalue_a98ea7cee0b1111e48e0800163e002d36` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `calc_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_coding` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_collect_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_data` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_data_collection_info_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_orig_value` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_orig_valueid` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `receive_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_state` varchar(1) DEFAULT '0',
 `f_build_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_meter_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_meter_change_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_meter_param_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `buildid_collecttime` (`f_build_id`,`f_collect_time`),
 KEY `meterid_collecttime_asc`      (`f_collect_time`,`f_meter_id`,`f_meter_param_id`),
 KEY `meterid_collecttime_desc` (`f_collect_time`,`f_meter_id`,`f_meter_param_id`),
 KEY `meterid_meterparamid` (`f_meter_id`,`f_meter_param_id`),
 KEY `f_meter_id` (`f_collect_time`,`f_meter_id`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19152255 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

please help me ,how can i optimize this terrible query

Comment: mysql table engine is innodb;row format is compact.

Comment: Could you possibly add an EXPLAIN output of that query too?

Comment: There is no `meter_id` in the schema link you provided!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  In the absence of that, here is a guess.  Add this index:

```
INDEX(meter_id, collect_time)  -- in this order
```

It will do 3 things:

- It will speed up the filtering (`WHERE`).  Note the `=` part must be first.
- It is "covering"; that is all the columns needed are in the index, thereby avoiding bouncing between the index and data BTrees.
- Adding a `DESC` so that you have `ORDER BY f_collect_time DESC, f_meter_id DESC` will let the index also handle the `ORDER BY` without having to do a sort.  But really, why is `meter_id` even mentioned in the `ORDER BY`??

Comment: I predict much less than one second, after making both of the recommended changes.

Comment: yes,you are right.i have solved this problem.i add the index(meter_id,collect_time),and everything is ok.thank you very much.